# Question regarding relative velocity of muzzle bullet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

[image]

A police jeep is chasing with, velocity of 45 km/h a thief in another jeep moving with velocity 153 km/h. Police fires a bullet with muzzle velocity of 180 m/s. The velocity it will strike the car of the thief is.

This is the original question from where my doubt came.

Now , we are given velocity of bullet w.r.t police and velocity of bullet w.r.t ground = 192.5m/s if we convert  45km/hr in m/s = 12.5m/s.

My question is that the speed with which the bullet moved is 192.5m/s or 180m/s?

Also ,I am not getting that is the thief jeep in front of police jeep since there is no separation between them given ?

Also , if we consider the thief to be in front of police . Then , if their travels 42.5m , then if bullet travels 150m/s w.r.t thief. It should be wrong right since it is travelling 150m but has travelled only 42.5m?

Comment: In your last paragraph you are mixing speed with distance, they are different things. Also it can probably be assumed that the police are chasing the thief as it is rarely the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all speeds are relative to the ground, air friction is negligible, and the gun is fired forwards, then you would add the gun's speed to the bullet's speed. Since the thief is moving away from the bullet you would subtract their speed from the bullet's speed to have the relative speed of the bullet to the thief. You will need to convert the thief's speed from km/h to m/s as well, because calculations need to be done with the same rates.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the muzzle velocity is measured relative to the gun, then the speed of the bullet relative to the ground is 192.5 m/s.  If the thief is being chased, then he is in front (and separated).  You are given no information about distance or time.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, there is nothing incorrect in your answer. I will upvote.

Comment: @AdrianHoward I suspect the downvote came from a user who believes the question is off-topic and should have been closed rather than answered.

Answer (score 1):

For velocity adding, you want to take the velocity of bullet with respect to police car and add that to the velocity of the police car respect to the floor. To see why this works. You kind of imagine the bullet being thrown from the police car. And since they're going the same direction, that would make the bullet even faster.

Now for adding velocity with the bullet respect to the thief car, you imagine yourself in the thief's car. If you're riding away at a velocity, would the bullet be slower or faster? It would be slower, which indicates, that the velocity of the bullet with respect to the thief's car must be SLOWER than the velocity with respect to the ground.